# Setting xml:base for an RDF using Jena tools

Tags: rdf, jena

I have a pair of identical ontologies, in n3 and RDF/XML format. For various reasons I need to be able to maintain available both formats. Let them be `big.n3` and `big.rdf`.

Given those files, I want to merge in a second n3 file with some constant data, edited by hand, and have the resulting N3 and RDF files belong to the same "base" namespace as the originals did, say `BASENS`.

In n3, this is simple enough: I merge both N3 files with rdfcat:

```
rdfcat -out n3 big.n3 constant.n3 > merged.n3
```

However for RDF:

```
rdfcat -out "RDF/XML" big.rdf constant.n3 > merged.rdf
```

The `merged.rdf` loses the base namespace from `big.rdf`, and so when opening it with a tool such as TopBraid, there is a conflict since the base NS (which defaults to the local RDF's file-URL since there's no real xml:base defined in the RDF) is no longer the same as the Ontology URI.

I can't seem to set the base namespace in rdfcat when outputting an RDF. I also tried rdfxml but couldn't find a way to use it to this end.

**Is there a command line jena tool to set the xml:base of an rdf, or some similar solution which doesn't involve programming some purpose-specific tool to achieve this?**

Comment: Once you read in the file, all the relative URIs should have been resolved against whatever base there is (either declared in the file, or determined from the filesystem), so there shouldn't be any need for an xml:base when you write out file (since there are no more relative URIs).  I think I understand what you're *trying* to do, but I'm not sure whether there's a way to read the file without already making the URIs all absolute.  This is particularly important because not every serialization supports a base.  E.g., N-Triples doesn't support a base declaration.

Comment: For instance, if you  put `<a> <b> <c>` in a N-Triples file and run `rdfcat` with it, you'll get the error "BadURIException: Only well-formed absolute URIrefs can be included in RDF/XML output: <l> Code: 57/REQUIRED_COMPONENT_MISSING in SCHEME: A component that is required by the scheme is missing."

Comment: All that is to say is that it's more important to set the base URI when you're *reading* the input files, rather than when you're writing things out.

Comment: @Joshua: thanks. In fact, the problem arises when inspecting the RDF/XML file in TopBraid, meaning it's at read time (of the merged RDF/XML). The file defines an Ontology (say `ont_uri a owl:Ontology`). TopBraid expects that ont_uri == xml:base for RDF/XML, however, the file defines ont_uri = BASENS, so TopBraid complains about duplicate ontologies (inferring an extra one with the default BASE).